# Could you tell me how it works? css html

Tags: html, css

http://tunein.com/radio/Verten-Radio-s150574/

If you check this web page, you will find that the green logo: "Verten Radio" is being included in the upper part. Could you explain how it works?

Comment: If you're asking how it's staying at the top of the page even as you scroll, it's because it is using CSS [fixed positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning).

Comment: And, javascript changes CSS properties (width, height, position) when user scrolls...

Comment: Thank you Marc and nevermind!

Comment: nevermind, your picture is nice BTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use `position : absolute;` and then assign `top` and `left` value to the element, therefore the green logo is being included in the upper part. I think that you should learn about [Position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) first, and then learn how to use [Google Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). it will help you inspect element, you won't get confused with HTML, CSS and JS technique used in other websites. hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Pakpoom!! I got it. I am learning Rails, now. And I got interested in seeing lots of web pages's source. Thanks anyway

Comment: @hirozaki It was my pleasure, friend. I hope you enjoy learning HTML, CSS, JavaScript. Anyway, if you find that my answer is okay, please accept this answer :)

Comment: Yeah, I did it. I don't know much about stackoverflow ..

Comment: @hirozaki No problem, my Japanese friend. For future questions, keep in mind that people are much likelier to help if you can demonstrate that you've put in an effort to solve the problem and gotten stuck on something specific.